# Update using External Id

Tags: data-loader, validation-rule, update, externalid

I understand UPDATE operation doesn't support ExternlID.

Is there any other way i can use Dataloader to update Salesforce records using external id ?

If i use UPSERT operation, i don't want to insert records where a matching ExternlId is not found. I am thinking I could use a validation rule to present inserting records when no ExternalId is found. However, i don't what should the criteria be to prevent inserting records?

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the trick of creating a simple validation rule

```
AND(
  ISNEW(),
  $User.Alias = "alias-of-user-doing-upsert"
)
```

Then put ALL_OR_NONE to false, and from all the errors, filter the onew with  the message you write on the validation rule. (so the rest of them would actually be update failures)